# Keep getting Segmentation fault and free() invalid pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I tried to build a program that simulates evolution. Forget that now, cause this is far from that.
To maximize the similarity to a natural environment I've had to use the rand function. But i get a segmentation error when i run the program with the rand function. When it isn't there, the program runs fine when i limit the iterations to 50 but says free(): invalid pointer when i increase it to 500. I need iterations in the order of millions.

The code after changing the rand function:
error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

int rand()
{
return 12359;
}


class space
    {
    public:
        bool map[10][10];
        int lightmap[100];
        int temperaturemap[100];
        space()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                    map[i][j]=false;
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                    lightmap[i]=40;
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                    temperaturemap[i]=40;
        }
        void ShowMap();
    }Space;


void space::ShowMap()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        cout<<endl;
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                if(map[i][j]==true)
                    cout<<".";
                else
                    cout<<" ";
            }
        }
}


class organism
    {
    public:
        static int ID;
            int thisID;
        int mapposition;
        int preferlight;
        int health;
        int LifeTicks;
        int prefertemperature;
        organism();
        organism(organism*);
        void turn();
        void mutate();
        void FindMyHealth();
        void move();
        void show();
    };

list <organism> life;

int organism::ID=0;

organism::organism()
        {
        thisID=ID;
        ID++;
        mapposition=17;
        LifeTicks=0;
        int posx = mapposition/10;
        int posy = mapposition%10;
        Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
        preferlight=5;
        prefertemperature=5;
        health=100;
        }

organism::organism(organism* parent)
            {
        thisID=ID;
        ID++;
        mapposition=17;
        LifeTicks=0;
        int posx = parent->mapposition/10;
        int posy = parent->mapposition%10;
        Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
        preferlight=parent->preferlight;
        prefertemperature=parent->prefertemperature;
        preferlight+=rand()%3-1;
        prefertemperature+=rand()%3-1;
        health=100;
        }

void organism::FindMyHealth()
    {
        health=100-LifeTicks-abs(prefertemperature-Space.temperaturemap[mapposition])-abs(preferlight-Space.lightmap[mapposition]);
        if(health<=0)
            health=-1;
    }   


void organism::show()
{
    cout<<"\n[$]ID"<<ID<<" [$]Temp"<<prefertemperature<<" [$]Light"<<preferlight<<" [$]Health"<<health<<" [$]Map_Position"<<mapposition<<"\n";
}


void organism::turn()
    {   
        move();
        if(rand()%45==7)
            {mutate();cout<<"LOL!!!";}
        LifeTicks++;
        FindMyHealth();
    }



void organism::move()
    {
        int BackUpMapPosition=mapposition;
        int posx = mapposition/10;
        int posy = mapposition%10;
        Space.map[posx][posy]=false;
        int i=0,x;

        do
         {
            x=rand()%101;
            if(mapposition > 90)
                x=2;
            else if(mapposition < 10)
                x=37;
        if(x>75)
            mapposition+=1;
        else if(x>50)
            mapposition-=1;

        else if(x>25)
            mapposition+=10;
        else
            mapposition-=10;
        if(i==10)
            break;
        posx = mapposition/10;
        posy = mapposition%10;
        }
        while(mapposition==17||Space.map[posx][posy]==true);

        if(i!=10)
            {
                posx = mapposition/10;
                posy = mapposition%10;
                Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
            }
        else
            {
                mapposition=BackUpMapPosition;
                posx = mapposition/10;
                posy = mapposition%10;
                Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
            }

    }


void organism::mutate() 
    {
        organism* x;
cout<<"LOL";
        *x=organism(this);
        life.push_front(*x);
        x->turn();
    }




void Begin()
    {
        {
            organism x;
            life.push_front(x);
        } 
        list <organism>::  iterator x;
        list <organism>::  iterator y;
        unsigned long int Ticks=0;
        x= life.begin();
        while(Ticks<500)
        {
            Ticks++;
            if(x==life.end())
                x=life.begin();
            if(x->health==-1)
                {
                y=x;
                ++y;
                life.erase(x);
                x=y;
                continue;cout<<"XX";
                }
            x->turn();
            advance(x,1);   
            cout<<Ticks<<"K"<<life.size()<<"L";
        }
            //life.front().show();


    }   


int main()
{
//srand((unsigned)time(0));
Begin();
}
```

and before:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<list>

using namespace std;


class space
    {
    public:
        bool map[10][10];
        int lightmap[100];
        int temperaturemap[100];
        space()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                    map[i][j]=false;
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                    lightmap[i]=40;
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                    temperaturemap[i]=40;
        }
        void ShowMap();
    }Space;


void space::ShowMap()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        cout<<endl;
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                if(map[i][j]==true)
                    cout<<".";
                else
                    cout<<" ";
            }
        }
}


class organism
    {
    public:
        static int ID;
            int thisID;
        int mapposition;
        int preferlight;
        int health;
        int LifeTicks;
        int prefertemperature;
                organism();
                organism(organism*);
        void turn();
        void mutate();
        void FindMyHealth();
        void move();
        void show();
    };

list <organism> life;

int organism::ID=0;

organism::organism()
        {
        thisID=ID;
        ID++;
        mapposition=17;
        LifeTicks=0;
        int posx = mapposition/10;
        int posy = mapposition%10;
        Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
        preferlight=5;
        prefertemperature=5;
        health=100;
        }

organism::organism(organism* parent)
            {
        thisID=ID;
        ID++;
        mapposition=17;
        LifeTicks=0;
        int posx = parent->mapposition/10;
        int posy = parent->mapposition%10;
        Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
        preferlight=parent->preferlight;
        prefertemperature=parent->prefertemperature;
        preferlight+=rand()%3-1;
        prefertemperature+=rand()%3-1;
        health=100;
        }

void organism::FindMyHealth()
    {
        health=100-LifeTicks-abs(prefertemperature-Space.temperaturemap[mapposition])-abs(preferlight-Space.lightmap[mapposition]);
        if(health<=0)
            health=-1;
    }   


void organism::show()
{
    cout<<"\n[$]ID"<<ID<<" [$]Temp"<<prefertemperature<<" [$]Light"<<preferlight<<" [$]Health"<<health<<" [$]Map_Position"<<mapposition<<"\n";
}


void organism::turn()
    {   
        move();
        if(rand()%45==7)
            {mutate();cout<<"LOL!!!";}
        LifeTicks++;
        FindMyHealth();
    }



void organism::move()
    {
        int BackUpMapPosition=mapposition;
        int posx = mapposition/10;
        int posy = mapposition%10;
        Space.map[posx][posy]=false;
        int i=0,x;

        do
         {
            x=rand()%101;
            if(mapposition > 90)
                x=2;
            else if(mapposition < 10)
                x=37;
        if(x>75)
            mapposition+=1;
        else if(x>50)
            mapposition-=1;

        else if(x>25)
            mapposition+=10;
        else
            mapposition-=10;
        if(i==10)
            break;
        posx = mapposition/10;
        posy = mapposition%10;
        }
        while(mapposition==17||Space.map[posx][posy]==true);

        if(i!=10)
            {
                posx = mapposition/10;
                posy = mapposition%10;
                Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
            }
        else
            {
                mapposition=BackUpMapPosition;
                posx = mapposition/10;
                posy = mapposition%10;
                Space.map[posx][posy]=true;
            }

    }


void organism::mutate()
    {
        organism* x;
cout<<"LOL";
        *x=organism(this);
        life.push_front(*x);
        x->turn();
    }




void Begin()
    {
        {
            organism x;
            life.push_front(x);
        } 
        list <organism>::  iterator x;
        list <organism>::  iterator y;
        unsigned long int Ticks=0;
        x= life.begin();
        while(Ticks<50)
        {
            Ticks++;
            if(x==life.end())
                x=life.begin();
            if(x->health==-1)
                {
                y=x;
                ++y;
                life.erase(x);
                x=y;
                continue;cout<<"XX";
                }
            x->turn();
            advance(x,1);   
            cout<<Ticks<<"K"<<life.size()<<"L"<<endl;
        }
            //life.front().show();


    }   


int main()
{
  srand((unsigned)time(0));

Begin();
}
```

Comment: *I've had to use the rand function* [No you haven't](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: I popped your code into my IDE to fix the indentation and because I've got compile on save turned on, the compiler spat out: *'x' is used uninitialized in this function* and pointed at `*x = organism(this);`. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is bad. Crom only knows where the program tried to go. Lesson here: Turn on the compiler warnings and pay attention to them. They're your firest line of defence against logic errors.

Comment: Now that I've got the code organized to my tastes, it looks like you have some recursion going on. make sure that when you crank the iterations up you aren't running the program off the end of the stack.

Comment: Fun fact: `list::erase` returns an iterator for the node after the erased node. `x = life.erase(x);` eliminates the `x`-`y` juggling.

Comment: `organism* x;` was never initialized.  `*x=organism(this);` is undefined behavior.  Probably will segfault.

Comment: `if (x == life.end()) x = life.begin();` will not help you if the list is empty and begin IS end. An invalid `x` can be used.

Comment: There are at least two fatal bugs here and there's no point continuing because we don't know which fatal bug is the fatal bug you are seeking. Recommendation: Don't write this much code without stopping and testing.

Comment: I don't understand. Why does x need to be initialized? ```organism* x;```

Answer (score 0):

> Keep getting Segmentation fault and free() invalid pointer

The error means: you have attempted to `free()` a pointer that was not allocated via `malloc()` family of functions.

This can happen when you try to `free` a wild (uninitialized) pointer, when you double-`free` some pointer, or when you `free` a pointer that is actually pointing to stack (local) or a global variable.

There are tools that help you diagnose such errors with minimal effort: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and [address sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Use them, and they'll likely tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Will do. Thank you!